# Django-Python admin-site add user text-fields gone

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Utilizing the default admin site at www.website.com/admin I click 'add user' and the page displays (see below) but with no text fields/labels.  I added a new model to an app... E.G. www.website.com/app1... and the text fields/labels showed and, since it was adding features of a user that did not exist yet, it redirected me to the same flawed defualt add-user page.  Please advise.

[image: Add user with no fields]

I made some changes to the files below in an app :

```
directory structure:
    website
      -app1
        -migrations
          -0001_initial.py
        -models.py
      -app2
      -website
        -settings.py
        -__init__.py
```

migration file '0001_initial.py' in app1:

```
# Generated by Django 2.0.6 on 2018-06-30 00:53

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
from django.contrib import admin, auth
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

initial = True

dependencies = [
    migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='UserProfile',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('description', models.CharField(default='', max_length=100)),
            ('city', models.CharField(default='', max_length=100)),
            ('website', models.URLField(default='')),
            ('email', models.EmailField(default='', max_length=254)),
            ('profile_pic', models.ImageField(upload_to='')),
            ('user', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
        ],
    ),
]
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    website = models.URLField(default='')
    email = models.EmailField(default='')
    profile_pic = models.ImageField()



def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.Create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

Comment: Have you made any changes to the user model? If you have then you may need to register the new model in the admin.

Comment: See above update with revisions.  I suppose I accidentally made changes to some default configuration settings...?

Comment: I am struggling to replicate the bug, I have added your user model and the default user page shows up fine still. Have you done anything with the admin registration anywhere. I suspect this is going to be the issue. It may not solve your admin problems but this article is great for django user auth. Look at the profile model. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html